# Private account by a attribute in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a proplem with this function. 
My attribute `'sv_trangThai'=2` , of course. i can log in. and if `sv_trangThai=1`, this account won't log in because of being locked.
Ok. 2:can log in and 1: being locked and can't log in.
Absolutely my code is running well but when i typed the wrong password or username, `i got "username or password is not true!"`.That's first case. Fine.
In case 2th, when i typed true password and username, i got the same `"username or password is not true".`
I wanna ask to how i should write to Show MessageBag:`"This account is being locked"` when i use case 2. instead of "username or password is not true".`enter code here`

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'sv_ma' =>'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ];
        $messages = [
            'sv_ma.required' => 'Please type code',
            'password.required' => 'please type password here',
            'password.min' => 'password is the least at**strong text** 6!!!!',

        ];
         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
         if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
            if (Auth::guard('sinhvien')->attempt(['sv_ma'=>$request->sv_ma,'password'=>$request->password,'sv_trangThai'=>2],$request->remember))
            {

                    return redirect()->intended('/trangchu');
            }
            else
            {
                 $errors = new MessageBag(['errorlogin' => 'username or password is not true!']);
                return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('sv_ma','remember'))->withErrors($errors);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$credentials = $request->only('sv_ma','password');

if(Auth::guard('sinhvien')->attempt($credentials, $request->remember)){
   $user = Auth:user();
   if($user->sv_trangThai == 1 ){
      //account locked
       Auth::logout();
       $errors = new MessageBag(['errorlogin' => 'Account Locked']);
       return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('sv_ma','remember'))->withErrors($errors);
   }

}else{
    $errors = new MessageBag(['errorlogin' => 'username or password is not true!']);
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('sv_ma','remember'))->withErrors($errors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must check the sv_ma and password what's return with this
**dd($request->sv_ma .'  '.$request->password );**

Second go to your database and check your password if is hashed or not if is not hashed you must add a new account but  the password should be hashed using bcrypt.